# url_regex sees only the domain part in the URL in Squid Proxy

Tags: squid

I configured Squid Proxy v4.13 with SSL bump on Ubuntu. I read about the url_regex directive and my objective is to access only https sites and block other. However it is not working for me as it sees only the domain part of the URL when i use url_regex directive.

For example,
1.) acl whitelist url_regex cric(info|buzz) allows cricbuzz.com and cricinfo.com and blocks other URL
2.) acl whitelist url_regex https:// blocks all URLs
My understanding is that if i have line 2 in conf file, the regex should match all URL starting with https:// right?
Also i tried using ssl::server_name_regex directive with no go. Do i have to modify squid.conf file in order to make this to work? Could someone explain me what's the issue?
Thanks in advance!!

Here is my conf file:

http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid/squidCA.pem

acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all

acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

acl whitelist url_regex https://
http_access allow whitelist
http_access deny all

include /etc/squid/conf.d/*

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 432

sslcrtd_program /usr/lib/squid/security_file_certgen -s /var/lib/squid/ssl_db -M 4MB
sslcrtd_children 5
ssl_bump server-first all
sslproxy_cert_error deny all

Answer (score 0):

Use https_port #https_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid/squidCA.pem

Use http_access #http_acces only serves to handle traffic without ssl, to block all unsafe traffic, just http_access deny all